# Why is my Repeater null in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm just starting a new project and I am getting some really weird stuff happening.

ASP.NET 3.5, VS2008.

I've tried rebuild, close VS, delete everything and get from svn again but I cannot understand why the repeater in the following is null on page_load.

I know this is going to be a headslapping moment. Help me out?

Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GalleryControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Site.UserControls.GalleryControl" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGalleries" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <li>wqe</li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class GalleryControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptGalleries.DataSource = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        rptGalleries.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Designer:

```
  public partial class GalleryControl {

    /// <summary>
    /// rptGalleries control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater rptGalleries;
}
```

Why is my repeater null? What the F is going on?

The referencing page has this:

```
<ux:GalleryControl runat="server" ID="uxGalleryControl"/>
```

The web.config has this (I've never had to do this before but my masterpage was complaining about not finding another user control).

```
<add tagPrefix="ux" namespace="Site.UserControls" assembly="Site" />
```

Comment: Very strange. Did you check your .aspx.designer.cs file for the repeater control?

Maybe for some reason the designer didnt autogenerate the reference? Ive seen that happen before.

Comment: yep it's there. Updated question.

Comment: I've just tried creating an entirely new control with the same effect. The page that references this has a DropDownList on it which is fine.

Comment: I've added a textbox to the usercontrol and that is also null... definitely something wrong with usercontrols loading in this project...

Comment: How are you instantiating the control?

Comment: I'm referencing it from an ASPX page which has a Master page. It's not the user control that's null it's the controls within it. It's controls collection contains no child controls yet the class contains the property. ASP.NET should look at the markup and instantiate any controls within. At least that's how it's always worked for me over the past 2 years....

Comment: What is the "Site" assembly? Is that the same assembly as your web application? Obviously it has to be, because you cant create user controls in assemblies outside your web app (only assemblies with custom controls).

Comment: Yes the Site assembly is my web application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After hours of head banging I have finally figured this out.

I was referencing the User controls in the web config as stated (I also tried the Register method with the Assembly). I think there's a weirdness with this method when the controls are in the same assembly. So referencing them like this:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/GalleryControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ux" TagName="GalleryControl" %>
```

Worked immediately.

I hope anyone else with the same problem finds this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, only to realise that the repeater in question was in the (massive) header template of another repeater.
Rearranging the header template in such a way that said repeater was outside, solved the issue...
Weird that there were no compiler errors though